# NSDateformatter wrong time zone

Tags: ios9, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm getting the following date form the server as a `string`.

```
"Fri, 09 Sep 2016 16:50:40 GMT"
```

I want this to be converted in to my local `timezone`, and I have this method to do that:

```
-(NSString *)convertDatetoLocalTimeZone:(NSString *)dateString {

    NSDateFormatter *serverFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [serverFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    [serverFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];

    NSDate *expDate = [serverFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSDateFormatter *userFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [userFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
    [userFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    return [userFormatter stringFromDate:expDate];

}
```

and now the converted date is :

```
"Fri, 09 Sep 2016 12:50:40 EDT"
```

As this is a string, I want to convert it to `NSDate` (OfCourse with same timezone). I expect that the converted `NSDate` will be showing the `EDT` timezone.

Here is what I have to convert the string back to `NSDate`:

```
-(NSDate *)getDateFromString:(NSString*)dateString{

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EDT"]];  //I also tried [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]
    return [df dateFromString:dateString];

}
```

The date returned is:

```
 2016-09-09 16:50:40 +0000 //this is in UTC
```

I also tried by setting the locale to `en_US`

My question is why the date formatter converts the `EDT` into `UTC` even though I set the time zone to `EDT` ?

Answer (score 0):

> I expect that the converted NSDate will be showing the EDT timezone.

That's your problem. `NSDate` does not have a time zone. An instance of `NSDate` represents a specific moment in time. It doesn't mean a specific moment in a specific location, just a specific moment.

If you print an `NSDate`, you see the UTC representation of the date. That does not mean that the date is UTC, only that UTC was used when printing it.

As a result of this, your `convertDatetoLocalTimeZone` method is already getting a valid `NSDate`. You don't need a separate `getDateFromString` method since you're already calculating the result of that method. It's always better to store `NSDate` values and convert them to strings when necessary, instead of storing them as strings and converting back to `NSDate`. Save the date in `convertDatetoLocalTimeZone`, don't save the string and then later convert back to `NSDate`.